# How to find out what this error means: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1129)

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

From a python app attempting to make an HTTPS request I'm hitting an error which I'm struggling to understand:

```
[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1129)
```

I presume this is coming from OpenSSL.  But besides the handshake failing, it doesn't tell me what the problem is.  IE: it doesn't tell me why the handshake failed or what step of it failed.

Various links on google give things to try, but give no reason why they might work.  I have tried them but nothing worked so far.  Based on these results I have tried:

- upgrading `certifi`
- running the certificate install script in mac python install directory
- upgrading the python version

Is there any way to get more information about this error?

---

Steffen Ullrich [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72138533/how-to-find-out-what-this-error-means-ssl-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure-sslv/73254780#comment127463089_72138533) that this error is server-side.  This may be useful to others debugging.  For us the problem was that we were not sending a client certificate when we were supposed to be.

Comment: Is that the full error?

Comment: @ewong there's a python stack trace but I doubt it's helpful in context of an error originating from openssl (written in c)

Comment: Handshake failure can be anything, but usually has nothing to do with certificate validation. Therefore doing anything with certifi or similar will not help. It might be no shared ciphers or protocol version, it might be required client certificates, it might be  that the server does not speak SSL at all ...

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yeah, that's why I was hoping there would be a way of getting more info out of OpenSSL about the cause

Comment: @PhilipCouling: usually not. The server is sending a TLS "alert handshake failure" and the client gets no further details about the reason from the server. Maybe one can find information in the server logs.

Comment: Oh!!! You've actually just given me more than I knew in these words *"The server is sending..."*.  Okay so this is server-side.  That actually helps.

Answer (score 0):

For now, just a work around - folks on this [fourm](https://bugs.gentoo.org/793884) led me to try

1. compare `openssl ciphers` (identical in both my good and bad environments)
2. `openssl s_client -connect news.somewhere.com:563` (worked)

then add the following python code based on output from the above:

```
import ssl
cntxt = ssl.create_default_context()
cntxt.set_ciphers("AES256-GCM-SHA384")
import nntplib
nntp = nntplib.NNTP_SSL('news.somewhere.com', ssl_context=cntxt)
```

which solved the SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE I was getting. (You will want to select the cipher that worked in that s_client test connection to your server.)

There are a dozen library and module version differences between my two environments, but in general the old environment uses python-3.9.7 and the new (broken but now running environment) uses python-3.10.5

Hopefully this narrows things down a bit.